# javascript calculator with click to calculate

Tags: javascript, function, calculator, getelementbyid

I have a working calculator on my website that is used for business expense savings estimation. currently the calculator auto-calculates in real time as the user inputs numbers.  i would like the user to have to click a calculate button in order to see any results. could someone please help as i am having a hard time adjusting the code myself.  here is the current code:

```js
function calc() {

  var cost = document.getElementById('phone').value * (.30) +
    document.getElementById('energy').value * (.05) +
    document.getElementById('cell').value * (.30) + document.getElementById('office').value * (.15) + document.getElementById('card').value *
    (.35) + document.getElementById('waste').value * (.5) +
    document.getElementById('payroll').value * (.5);

  document.getElementById('cost').value = (cost * 12).toFixed(2);

}
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="33%" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" style="text-align: center"><strong>  
  Category</strong>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center"><strong>Monthly Expenses</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="47%" valign="top">Telephone &amp; Internet</td>
      <td width="53%">
        <input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" onchange="calc
  ()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">Energy</td>
      <td>
        <input name="energy" id="energy" type="text" onchange="calc()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">Cell Phone</td>
      <td>
        <input name="cell" id="cell" type="text" onchange="calc()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">Office Supplies</td>
      <td>
        <input name="office" id="office" type="text" onchange="calc()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">Merchant Card Fees</td>
      <td>
        <input name="card" id="card" type="text" onchange="calc()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">Waste Removal</td>
      <td>
        <input name="waste" id="waste" type="text" onchange="calc()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="31" valign="top">3rd Party Payroll Fees</td>
      <td>
        <input name="payroll" id="payroll" type="text" onchange="calc  
  ()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div align="center">
    <table width="33%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="54%" height="31" valign="top"><strong>Estimated Annual 
  Savings:</strong>
        </td>
        <td width="46%">
          <textarea name="cost" rows="1" id="cost" readonly style="overflow:hidden" input type="number"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your inputs are set up to call `calc()` whenever their `onchange` event is fired.  This happens whenever the value is changed and the input is blurred (no longer in focus).

Remove the `onchange="calc()"` attribute on all your inputs, and add a button whever it makes sense to on your page with `onclick="calc()"`:

```
<button onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  seems so obvious now!  works perfect

Answer (score 0):

Place button with Javascript event **outside** form

```
<button onclick="calc();">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all onchange="calc()" and add this html code to your page, that's it.

```
   <button onclick="calc()">Calculate Expenses</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the call to  onchange="calc()" from all.
- Put `<div align="center">
  <table width="33%" border="0">
  <tr>
      <td align="Center">
              <input type="button"  value="Click To Calculate" onclick="calc()" />
      </td>
  </tr>
  </div>`